# B-Trees and its applications

Tags: b-tree, abstract-data-type

I am studying B Trees and performing their respective implementation in C++. So, I will submit a final project for the course "Analysis and Design of Algorithms I", where the emphasis is on the study of abstract data types, programming techniques for optimizing the complexity of the algorithms and, precisely, planning algorithms on various structures.

The problem is that only deliver the work of the implementation of the structure and their respective operations sounds a bit crude. Then I have to find an application to includ in my project. The point is that the only application that I've found is the creation of a database engine or a file system for an operative system. I'm not sure about database design and to make matters worse, the databases uses B+Trees.

So, can you list some applications that can be implemented using B Trees?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, **file systems** and **databases** are the first thing that come to mind with B-Trees.

But, in general, every application that stores some kind of sortable data could be stored with a B-Tree. So you could just write a small address book where you store names, addresses, etc., you can back this with your own B-Tree implementation. (Of course, in practice, it's usually a better idea to use an existing library or database for that ...)